# Hostname error on my Slicehost Ubuntu server

Tags: ssl, postfix, hostname, tls

Like many folks who upgraded to Rails 2.2, I got an exception raised when sending an email. This version of Rails or later does require using tls for sending emails. The message in the production log file says:

```
hostname was not match with the server certificate
```

I did a whole lot of research and work on this and did everything I could. I changed my slice's hostname to ohlalaweb.com. If I run the command 'hostname' at the CL I get:

```
ohlalaweb.com
```

Postfix seems to work fine. I can send emails from the CL to my gmail, yahoo, and google apps gmail accounts with no problems. Here is the result of cat /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = /etc/mailname

smmtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ohlalaweb.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ohlalaweb.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
# SA created next line to force postfix to use self create certificate
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = ohlalaweb.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

I have regenerated the ssl keys with the ohlalaweb.com host name.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

ohlalaweb.com is a domain name, not a host name, at least it shouldn't be.  A hostname would be something like 'mail' in 'mail.ohlalaweb.com'.  The certificate validation is failing because the servers name does not match what is in the CommonName field of the certificate.

The easiest solution is to change your server's name to match the entry in the CommonName field of the certificate.